# How to stop bootstrap div / thumbnail from adjusting according to screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am creating a slider of thumbnail like [this sample](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/infinite-carousel-loop). To achieve this i want to resist bootstrap thumbnail (div) from getting arranged as stack when display size is reduced. JSFIDDLE:- [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zL0tmqcm/9/)

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="..." alt="..."/>
            <div class="caption">
              <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
              <p>...</p>
              <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="..." alt="..."/>
            <div class="caption">
              <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
              <p>...</p>
              <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="..." alt="..."/>
            <div class="caption">
              <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
              <p>...</p>
              <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>   
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, change your column definitions to:

```
col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zL0tmqcm/10/)

Comment: That has stopped the thumbnail from getting stacked over each other, but i want to show only two div's upfront when the min-width=992px; and only one div when min-width=768px. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is mobile-first, so the smaller column sizes are used if a bigger variant is not found. To have it behave the same for all screen sizes, just define the smallest.

If you set it up to show as three columns in the smallest size, it should do the trick eg.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Here is a revised fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cv3pf3e7/) which I think is what you're aiming for.

Comment: Thanks. That has stopped the thumbnail from getting stacked over each other, but i want to show only two div's upfront when the min-width=992px; and only one div when min-width=768px;.